# How to use the Data from two pages for insert to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, dart

I'm new on flutter and I am trying to do a table and store data from TextFields, those are in two separated classes. I also have the separated page for the SQLite database. I had created the controllers for each textfield but now I don't know how to use the values in the textfields from _MyHomePageState class and the values in the textfields from Detalle class to insert in the table, here is the code (I cut a little bit the code, there are more textfields):

Here is the first page, here are few textfields which must be filled:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    TextEditingController dateCtl = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController operad = TextEditingController();


  List<String> operadores = ['AP','EM'];
  List<String> cargadores = ['VOLVO L150H', 'CAT 966H'];

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[

          TextFormField(
            controller: dateCtl,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Seleccione Fecha",),
            onTap: () async{
                 DateTime date;
                 var formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
                date = await showDatePicker(
                                       context: context,
                                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                      firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3)),
                                      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 3)));
                 dateCtl.text = formatter.format(date);
                 
              }

            ),
     Divider(height: 10.0,),         
         DropDownField(
        controller: operad,
        required: false,
        strict: true,
        hintText: 'Seleccione Operador',
        icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
        itemsVisibleInDropdown: 4,
        items: operadores,
        setter: (dynamic newValue) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          operadores = newValue;

        }
    ),
               
Divider(height: 10.0,),

    FloatingActionButton.extended(
      heroTag: null,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(16, 172, 40,80),
      icon: Icon(Icons.subdirectory_arrow_right),
      label: Text("Ir a Registrar Horas", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic) ),
      onPressed: (){

Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Detalle()));
        
              },
            )
        
                  ]
                ),
              ),
        
            );
        
          }
        
        }
```

When tap on the button, the app goes to the second page where there are some other textfields:

```
 class Detalle extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

TextEditingController zona1 = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController zona2 = TextEditingController();

List<String> materiales = [
  'Carbón',
  'Cascarilla',
  'Arcilla',
  ];


    return Scaffold(

appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Registro de Horas"),
      ),
      body: Column(
      
      children:<Widget>[
        DropDownField(
           
        required: false,
        strict: true,
        textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        hintText: 'Escriba Material',
        icon: Icon(Icons.filter_hdr),
        itemsVisibleInDropdown: 3,
        items: materiales,
        setter: (dynamic newValue) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          materiales = newValue;

        }
    ),

    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      
      children: <Widget>[   
       
        Container(
        width: 200,
        child: 
        TextField(
        controller: zona1,  
        autofocus: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(icon: Icon(Icons.device_hub),
                                    hintText: "Escriba Zona 1"),
        )
        ),

        Container(
        width: 200,
        child: 
        TextField(
        controller: zona2,  
        autofocus: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(icon: Icon(Icons.device_hub),
                                    hintText: "Escriba Zona 2"),
        )
        ),
],),

Divider(height: 20,),
   
SizedBox(width: 50,),

        Container(
         width: 200,
         height: 50,
         child: 
        FloatingActionButton.extended(
          heroTag: null,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(16, 172, 40,80),
        label: Text('Grabar Material', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),  
        icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle),
       onPressed: () { },
          
        )
       ),
],),
             
  );

  }
 }
```

Here is the code for the SQLite page:

```
class DBProvider {

  static Database _database; 
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  DBProvider._();

  Future<Database> get database async {

    if ( _database != null ) return _database;

    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }


  initDB() async {

    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final path = join( documentsDirectory.path, 'HorasMaquina.db' );

    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onOpen: (db) {},
      onCreate: ( Database db, int version ) async {
        await db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE HorasMaquina ('
          ' ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,'
          ' Fecha DATE,'
          ' Operador TEXT,'
          ' Cargador TEXT,'
          ' Zona1 TEXT,'
          ' Zona2 TEXT,'
          ')'
        );
      }
    
    );

  }


 Future<void> insertRegistrotabla(Registrotabla hm) async {

  final Database db = await database;

  await db.insert(
    'HorasMaquina',
    hm.toMap(),
    conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
  );
}

}


 class Registrotabla{

final String fecha;
final String operador;
final String cargador;
final String z1;
final String z2;

Registrotabla({

this.fecha, this.operador, this.cargador, this.z1, this.z2,

});

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      
'Fecha' : fecha,
'Operador' : operador,
'Cargador' : cargador,
'Zona1' : z1,
'Zona2' : z2,
    };
  }
 }
```

So the problem is that I still can't use the controllers to set the values and insert in the table.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: make a constructor for a Detalle class and pass your data from MyHomePage and on Detalle page call your provider

Comment: Thank you, now I will chek how to make it, thank you so much.

Comment: Stellar, maybe you can give me a hand in creating the constructor please, I think that I can't find the correct way or I am really lost....